# Printing only the first 25 concordances in python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, text-processing, corpus

I am working on a task from my university and I have no idea how to print only the first 25 concordances of a word instead of the whole  list.

Comment: Add some more details,like current output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice when you ask in StackOverflow, You add also the question(details) or what you have tried to solve it

```
words = "I am working on a task from my university and I have no idea how..."
print(words[:25])
list = ['a','b','c','d'.....]
print(list[:25])
```

Output

```
"working on a task from my"
['a', 'b'.....]
```